# Retina & non-retina compatible UIImage stacking and positioning

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I often need to position and stack two `UIImages` into an `UIView`. 
For example, placing a picture frame around (behind) a photo, and then displaying it. Specifying the position by modifying the image's frame will not work with both Retina and non-retina devices because the hardcoded frame values will not scale.

For example, if I have a photo frame who's image is `56x56 (retina)` and the actual image is `52x52 (retina)`, it needs to be placed at `CGRectMake(2, 2, 54, 54)` on top of the photo frame. But if the user is on non-retina this will fail since those values will be incorrect (they're now `CGRectMake(1, 1, 27, 27)`).

What is the correct way for resolution-safe image processing? Is there a way to combine two images (each with regular and `@2x.pngs`) that will display correctly on either screen type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIScreen scale property. It's a readonly property. In devices prior to iPhone 4 (non-retina displays) this value will be 1.0, but with retina displays the value is 2.0. So you can store this property to a local variable, say called CGFloat scaleFactor and multiply it with the values above:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor=[[UIScreen mainscreen] scale];
... = CGRectMake(1.0*scalefactor,1.0*scaleFactor,27.0*scaleFactor,27.0*scaleFactor);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Is this the preferred way to manipulate images? Does this still apply if I begin to do more advanced image manipulation? Is there a way to convert the contents of an image buffer to both image versions needed and let the framework handle choosing which to display, akin to have filename.png and filename@2x.png?

Comment: This practice is from WWDC2011 ScrollView. Don't really know about converting contents of an image but I'm sure this practice is the preferred one as Apple engineers themselves recommend it.